# JCR / Jackrabit / Derby - slow IO with binary data when restoring Version on Linux

Tags: linux, io, derby, jackrabbit, jcr

I store default nodes with binary data (3mb) on it. Change them and save again. Later I want to get an older version back, so I use the restore function. On Windows this works at normal speed (maximum 1 sec). But on Linux it takes about 20 sec.

Has anybody an idea what makes it such slow? Here the stacktrace from the point where it is slow:

```
Daemon Thread [ajp-bio-8011-exec-40] (Evaluating)   
RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]   
DirRandomAccessFile4(RandomAccessFile).write(byte[], int, int) line: 466    
LogAccessFile.writeToLog(byte[], int, int, long) line: not available    
LogAccessFile.flushDirtyBuffers() line: not available [local variables unavailable] 
LogAccessFile.switchLogBuffer() line: not available 
LogAccessFile.reserveSpaceForChecksum(int, long, long) line: not available  
LogToFile.appendLogRecord(byte[], int, int, byte[], int, int) line: not available   
FileLogger.logAndDo(RawTransaction, Loggable) line: not available   
Xact.logAndDo(Loggable) line: not available 
LoggableActions.doAction(RawTransaction, BasePage, Loggable) line: not available    
LoggableActions.actionInsert(RawTransaction, BasePage, int, int, Object[], FormatableBitSet, LogicalUndo, byte, int, boolean, int, DynamicByteArrayOutputStream, int, int) line: not available  
StoredPage(BasePage).insertLongColumn(BasePage, LongColumnException, byte) line: not available  
StoredPage(BasePage).insertAllowOverflow(int, Object[], FormatableBitSet, int, byte, int, RecordHandle) line: not available 
StoredPage(BasePage).insert(Object[], FormatableBitSet, byte, int) line: not available  
HeapController.doInsert(DataValueDescriptor[]) line: not available  
HeapController.insertAndFetchLocation(DataValueDescriptor[], RowLocation) line: not available   
RowChangerImpl.insertRow(ExecRow) line: not available   
InsertResultSet.normalInsertCore(LanguageConnectionContext, boolean) line: not available    
InsertResultSet.open() line: not available  
GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Activation, boolean, long) line: not available 
GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Activation, long) line: not available  
EmbedPreparedStatement40(EmbedStatement).executeStatement(Activation, boolean, boolean) line: not available 
EmbedPreparedStatement40(EmbedPreparedStatement).executeStatement(Activation, boolean, boolean) line: not available 
EmbedPreparedStatement40(EmbedPreparedStatement).execute() line: not available  
PoolablePreparedStatement(DelegatingPreparedStatement).execute() line: 172  
DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute() line: 172 
DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute() line: 172 
DerbyConnectionHelper(ConnectionHelper).execute(PreparedStatement, Object[]) line: 473  
DerbyConnectionHelper(ConnectionHelper).reallyExec(String, Object...) line: 303 
ConnectionHelper$1.call() line: 285 
ConnectionHelper$1.call() line: 281 
ConnectionHelper$1(ConnectionHelper$RetryManager<T>).doTry() line: 486  
DerbyConnectionHelper(ConnectionHelper).exec(String, Object...) line: 281   
BundleDbPersistenceManager$DbBlobStore.put(String, InputStream, long) line: 1214    
BundleWriter.writeState(NodePropBundle$PropertyEntry) line: 240 
BundleWriter.writeBundle(NodePropBundle) line: 132  
BundleBinding.writeBundle(OutputStream, NodePropBundle) line: 164   
DerbyPersistenceManager(BundleDbPersistenceManager).storeBundle(NodePropBundle) line: 885   
DerbyPersistenceManager(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager).putBundle(NodePropBundle) line: 769   
DerbyPersistenceManager(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager).storeInternal(ChangeLog) line: 686    
DerbyPersistenceManager(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager).store(ChangeLog) line: 563    
DerbyPersistenceManager(BundleDbPersistenceManager).store(ChangeLog) line: 477  
SharedItemStateManager$Update.end() line: 770   
SharedItemStateManager.update(ChangeLog, EventStateCollectionFactory) line: 1492    
XAItemStateManager(LocalItemStateManager).update(ChangeLog) line: 400   
XAItemStateManager.update(ChangeLog) line: 354  
XAItemStateManager(LocalItemStateManager).update() line: 375    
VersionManagerImplBase$WriteOperation.save() line: 470  
VersionManagerImpl$6.perform(SessionContext) line: 253  
SessionState.perform(SessionOperation<T>) line: 216 
VersionManagerImpl.perform(SessionOperation<T>) line: 96    
VersionManagerImpl.restore(Version[], boolean) line: 225    
VersionManagerImpl.restore(Version, boolean) line: 217
```

My config can you point me to a new one?:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.5//EN"
"http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.5.dtd">
<!-- Example Repository Configuration File
Used by
- org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigTest.java
-
-->
<Repository>
    <!--
    virtual file system where the repository stores global state
    (e.g. registered namespaces, custom node types, etc.)
    -->
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
    </FileSystem>
    <!--
    security configuration
    -->
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <!--
        security manager:
        class: FQN of class implementing the JackrabbitSecurityManager interface
        -->
        <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
            <!--
            workspace access:
            class: FQN of class implementing the WorkspaceAccessManager interface
            -->
            <!-- <WorkspaceAccessManager class="..."/> -->
            <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/security.xml"/> -->
        </SecurityManager>
        <!--
        access manager:
        class: FQN of class implementing the AccessManager interface
        -->
        <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleAccessManager">
            <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/access.xml"/> -->
        </AccessManager>
        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleLoginModule">
            <!--
            anonymous user name ('anonymous' is the default value)
            -->
            <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
            <!--
            administrator user id (default value if param is missing is 'admin')
            -->
            <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>
    <!--
    location of workspaces root directory and name of default workspace
    -->
    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>
    <!--
    workspace configuration template:
    used to create the initial workspace if there's no workspace yet
    -->
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <!--
        virtual file system of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the FileSystem interface
        -->
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
        </FileSystem>
        <!--
        persistence manager of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the PersistenceManager interface
        -->
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.DerbyPersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${wsp.home}/db;create=true"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
        <!--
        Search index and the file system it uses.
        class: FQN of class implementing the QueryHandler interface
        -->
        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="textFilterClasses" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PlainTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsWordTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsExcelTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsPowerPointTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PdfTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.OpenOfficeTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.RTFTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.HTMLTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.XMLTextExtractor"/>
            <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="2"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>
    <!--
    Configures the versioning
    -->
    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <!--
        Configures the filesystem to use for versioning for the respective
        persistence manager
        -->
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>
        <!--
        Configures the persistence manager to be used for persisting version state.
        Please note that the current versioning implementation is based on
        a 'normal' persistence manager, but this could change in future
        implementations.
        -->
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.DerbyPersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${rep.home}/version/db;create=true"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>
    <!--
    Search index for content that is shared repository wide
    (/jcr:system tree, contains mainly versions)

    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
        <param name="textFilterClasses" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PlainTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsWordTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsExcelTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsPowerPointTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PdfTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.OpenOfficeTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.RTFTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.HTMLTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.XMLTextExtractor"/>
        <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="2"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>
    -->
</Repository>
```

Correct config was:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.5//EN"
"http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.5.dtd">
<!-- Example Repository Configuration File
Used by
- org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigTest.java
-
-->
<Repository>
    <!--
    virtual file system where the repository stores global state
    (e.g. registered namespaces, custom node types, etc.)
    -->
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
    </FileSystem>

    <!--
        data store configuration
    -->
    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore"/>

    <!--
    security configuration
    -->
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <!--
        security manager:
        class: FQN of class implementing the JackrabbitSecurityManager interface
        -->
        <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
            <!--
            workspace access:
            class: FQN of class implementing the WorkspaceAccessManager interface
            -->
            <!-- <WorkspaceAccessManager class="..."/> -->
            <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/security.xml"/> -->
        </SecurityManager>
        <!--
        access manager:
        class: FQN of class implementing the AccessManager interface
        -->
        <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleAccessManager">
            <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/access.xml"/> -->
        </AccessManager>
        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleLoginModule">
            <!--
            anonymous user name ('anonymous' is the default value)
            -->
            <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
            <!--
            administrator user id (default value if param is missing is 'admin')
            -->
            <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>
    <!--
    location of workspaces root directory and name of default workspace
    -->
    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>
    <!--
    workspace configuration template:
    used to create the initial workspace if there's no workspace yet
    -->
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <!--
        virtual file system of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the FileSystem interface
        -->
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
        </FileSystem>
        <!--
        persistence manager of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the PersistenceManager interface
        -->
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.DerbyPersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${wsp.home}/db;create=true"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
        <!--
        Search index and the file system it uses.
        class: FQN of class implementing the QueryHandler interface
        -->
        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="textFilterClasses" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PlainTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsWordTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsExcelTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsPowerPointTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PdfTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.OpenOfficeTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.RTFTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.HTMLTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.XMLTextExtractor"/>
            <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="2"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>
    <!--
    Configures the versioning
    -->
    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <!--
        Configures the filesystem to use for versioning for the respective
        persistence manager
        -->
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>
        <!--
        Configures the persistence manager to be used for persisting version state.
        Please note that the current versioning implementation is based on
        a 'normal' persistence manager, but this could change in future
        implementations.
        -->
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.DerbyPersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${rep.home}/version/db;create=true"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>
    <!--
    Search index for content that is shared repository wide
    (/jcr:system tree, contains mainly versions)

    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
        <param name="textFilterClasses" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PlainTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsWordTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsExcelTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.MsPowerPointTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.PdfTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.OpenOfficeTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.RTFTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.HTMLTextExtractor,org.apache.jackrabbit.extractor.XMLTextExtractor"/>
        <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="2"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>
    -->
</Repository>
```

Comment: What version of Jackrabbit do you use? With older versions of Jackrabbit (that do not use the DataStore) the performance problem might be related to storing the binary within the database. Newer versions of Jackrabbit store binaries in the file system (FileDataStore) by default, which should be fast.

Comment: hi, i use "2.4.1" is this an old version?

Comment: 2.4.1 is a new version - but it seems you use old configuration files (repository.xml and workspace.xml), because in your case it uses the (old) DbBlobStore and not the FileDataStore.

Comment: hi i've added my config, is this the old one? where can i find a new one?

Comment: I have added an answer where I have described the main two options (just add the FileDataStore to the existing config file, and migrate to a new repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using an old configuration file, where the `FileDataStore` is not used. To use it, you can either:

- Configure the `FileDataStore` in the existing `repository.xml` as described in the [Jackrabbit Wiki page for the DataStore](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore#How_to_Configure_the_File_Data_Store) (this may require to change the doctype), or
- Migrate your repository to the new version of Jackrabbit, as described in the [Jackrabbit Wiki page for Backup and Migration](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/BackupAndMigration).

Migrating the data has the advantage that the existing binaries are also moved to the FileDataStore, which should reduce the repository size.

Comment: hi thanks that did it, i was fortunately in the situation that i didn't have to migrate old data thank you!